# Correlating responses to requests in logica SMPP async mode

Tags: java, smpp

I'm trying to implement an SMPP client using logica SMPP APIs.

The problem i'm facing is, How to map the request pdu with response pdu in an async mode? I thought i can do that using CommandId and sequence number. But the CommandId return by logica simulator is not equal to the request CommandId.

Example :

```
Enquire Link Comman ID (Request) = 21
Enquire Link Comman ID (async response from simulator) = -2147483627
```

Please tell me how I can map the request event with response event in async mode.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [protocol definition PDF](http://opensmpp.logica.com/CommonPart/Documentation/external/SMPP-IF-SPEC.v3.3.pdf) Table 6.1 on page 16, you can find that the field used for correlation is not `CommandID` (that defines the type of request) but `Sequence No`.

From the document:

> A sequence number allowing requests and responses to be associated.
>   Allocation of this reference number is the responsibility of the
>   originator, who should ensure that the number is monotonically
>   increasing for each submitted request. The associated response packet
>   must preserve this field.

Comment: Thanks for the response. During mapping i have to identified the event as their will be responses from multiple events, that's why i needed the CommanID.

Comment: From Doc i got the answer. All i need to do was unset 31 bit ( In general a response command identifier will be identical to the corresponding request command identifier, but
with bit 31 set. )